# How to connect raspberry pi to separate wifi's

Tags: networking, ssh, wpa, wpa-supplicant

I have a headless pi setup and I want it to connect to two different wifi's at two separate houses. This is how my wpa_supplicant.conf is setup:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
     ssid="SSID"
     psk="password"
     priority=2
}

network={
     ssid="opennetwork"
     psk=NONE
     priority=1
}
```

Right now i'm only able to be connected to my first network, as the other one is somewhere else. If my wpa_supplicant.conf file has only that network listed it connects fine. But, if I have it set up like this, it doesn't connect anywhere. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: That's what I want it to do. I just want it to check if there is one of the available networks and to join it if possible. But if I put more than one network in it won't connect to anything at all. should I get rid of the priority tag?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question correctly the first time -- I though you were trying to  connect to two networks simultaneously using an additional adapter.  Anyway, it should work, who know why not -- but TBH I just swap configs when I want a separate interface.  Will explain a simple way to do that in an answer.

Comment: What does `sudo iw dev wlan0 info` show?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it does not work properly; if it does not find the first network it should look for the other.  You might debug this by looking at `wpa_supplicant`'s output -- I am not sure where it is by default or if `wpa_supplicant` has its own service by default on RpiOS/Raspbian (I use customized dhcpcd scripts to manage that and discard the defaults when I configure a system).

So you could look into that.  However, it's simple enough to swap config files, although it becomes awkward if you are moving a headless pi since it is a bit manual.  If you have two files in `/etc/wpa_supplicant`, *neither of which is called `wpa_supplicant.conf`,* you can do this:

```
> cd /etc/wpa_supplicant; ls
one.conf
two.conf
> ln -s one.conf wpa_supplicant.conf; ls
one.conf
two.conf
wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The last one is a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), basically, provides an alias for `one.conf`.  To reverse the situation:

```
> rm wpa_supplicant.conf  # <- Only deletes the symlink
> ls -l two.conf wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Then restart dhcpcd:

```
systemctl restart dhcpcd
```

Check `pidof wpa_supplicant` before and after that if it does not work. If they are the same, then you need to stop `dhcpcd`, check and if necessary kill (or stop, if there is a service) `wpa_supplicant`, and then start `dhcpcd`.

Comment: Truly, this is *"thinking outside the box"*  :)

Answer (score 1):

I have 8 networks in my `wpa_supplicant.conf` - some on different continents and I can move seamlessly between them.

There is no point in priority unless multiple networks are visible.

Your file looks OK but not sure if `psk=NONE` is affecting results.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. I just went into raspberry pi config `sudo raspi-config`, went to network, and added a new network ssid. Then it automatically updated the wpa_supplicant file.

Comment: Pray tell, what are the contents of the `raspi-config`-generated `wpa_supplicant.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem once, you may try to use GUI to join the wifi network if you have the chance, it will update your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file regarding your network.